# Microsoft Office Access database engine cannot open or write to the file

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

When running SSIS package from the server, I get the following error

> SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
>   An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft Access Database Engine" Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "The Microsoft Access database engine cannot open or write to the file ''. It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view and write its data."

The file is saved on a shared drive and no one is using this file at the moment.

Comment: Could you please provide information about how the package is being executed?  This would help determine what user is trying to access the file share.  Is it via sql agent - if so, is it running under the sql agent service or a proxy?  If it's sql agent service, what account is that running under?  Any details about this will help.

Comment: To add to @MarkWojciechowicz once you determine the account in question confirm they have read/write to the a) SHARE permissions (sharing tab) and b) the FILE permissions (security tab) on the folder and files in question.